# Can a DNS client distinguish if the answer they received was based on a wildcard record or a specific match?

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

I had a `*` record on one of our zones and I changed it. But when I queried certain, random names on that zone from public DNS servers, I still received the old IP address.

This makes no sense to me. The server I queried could not know the correct IP address for the name, unless they know there was a wildcard record. Otherwise, they would have to ask our name servers.

When I query our own name servers for the same name, they would return the new IP address.

So, what's going on?

Comment: Only your servers know about the wildcard.  The wildcard is a special record that says 'answer all queries I don't have a specific entry for with this', no one's asking for the wildcard address.  What you're seeing is completely normal dns behavior (cached responses).  If you know you're going to change IPs you should lower the TTL in advance.

Comment: @yoonix: So, why am I seeing the old IP when I query a *random* name on that zone? Random, as in `5571f913b637ef1f27f14fb5`, nothing that exists as an entry. Shouldn't that *always* cause a query to our servers? As mentioned, when I query the same name on our servers, I get the new IP.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg Random, as in that you're confident there had been no such query issued before the IP changed?

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist: Yes. The zone contains only 1 A/AAAA record for `www` and the wildcard. The wildcard is what I changed.

Comment: Without the actual domain to look at, I can't really answer that.  Maybe one of your servers is still giving out the old address.

Comment: The zone is `fm.mg`. Feel free to compare queries against `ns1.hartwig-at.de` and `8.8.8.8`. Maybe you can enlighten me :P

Comment: ns6.gandi.net is showing the old IP still.

Comment: @yoonix: Argh, of course. They can transfer the whole zone :P That's probably the reason

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had a quick look to see if all the authoritative nameservers have synced.

```
$ dig +nssearch fm.mg
SOA ns1.hartwig-at.de. hostmaster.hartwig-at.de. 2015022400 86400 10800 2419200 3600 from server 217.70.177.40 in 8 ms.
SOA ns1.hartwig-at.de. hostmaster.hartwig-at.de. 2015060502 86400 10800 2419200 3600 from server 2a00:1158:3::b6 in 25 ms.
SOA ns1.hartwig-at.de. hostmaster.hartwig-at.de. 2015060502 86400 10800 2419200 3600 from server 134.119.4.37 in 26 ms.
SOA ns1.hartwig-at.de. hostmaster.hartwig-at.de. 2015060502 86400 10800 2419200 3600 from server 37.200.99.108 in 28 ms.
SOA ns1.hartwig-at.de. hostmaster.hartwig-at.de. 2015060502 86400 10800 2419200 3600 from server 2a00:1158:3::87 in 28 ms.
$
```

It appears that `217.70.177.40` is serving an older version of the zone, which probably explains the variations in results.

Comment: Sweet. I learned a new `dig` command :) Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5):

If you are not using DNSSEC there is no definitive way for the client to see if a reply was produced by a `*` record in the zone or by an exact match.

The client could use heuristic by comparing the answers produced by looking up the desired name to the answers produced by looking up a random string of characters. If the answers are identical it is likely a `*` record and if the answers are different it is likely not a `*` record.

If the zone is signed offline with DNSSEC it is however possible for a client to see if a `*` record was used. This is because the name used in the signature will actually contain a literal `*` character, which will prove that the answer was produced using a `*` record. Additionally NSEC3 can provide a signature showing that the requested name could not be answered without using the `*` record.